# getline has a strange behaviour in reading a text file

Tags: c++, encoding, getline

I have a strange behaviour with a piece of code I have wrote. There is the code :

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"

#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <optional>

namespace xml = pugi;

void read_ascii_file(const std::string& filename)
{
  std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

  if(!file) {
    std::cerr << "[ERREUR - read_ascii_file] Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier " << filename << "! Vérifier son existence." << std::endl;
    abort();
  }

  std::string tmp;
  while(std::getline(file, tmp))
    {
      //Do nothing here
    }
  file.close();
}

class Foo{

public:
  Foo(const xml::xml_document& doc)
  {
    _base_node = doc.child("test");

    std::string id = _base_node.child("data1").child_value("id");
    std::cout << "id from constructor " << id <<std::endl;
  }

  void bar()
  {
    std::string id = _base_node.child("data2").child_value("id");
    std::cout << "id from bar " << id <<std::endl;
  }

private:
  xml::xml_node _base_node;

};

std::optional<Foo> make(const std::string& filename)
{
  xml::xml_document doc;
  xml::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file(filename.c_str());

  if(result.status != xml::xml_parse_status::status_ok)
    return {};
  else
    return Foo(doc);
}

int main()
{
  std::string filename = "xml_test.dat";
  std::optional<Foo> f = make(filename);

  if(!f)
    std::abort();
  else
    {
      std::string filename = "lbl-maj_for_test.dat";
      //read_ascii_file(filename);
      f->bar();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The file xml_test.dat is :

```
<test>
  <data1>
    <id>1</id>
  </data1>
  <data2>
    <id>2</id>
  </data2>
</test>
```

This code giving an output :

> id from constructor 1
>
> id from bar 2

But when I uncomment the line `//read_ascii_file(filename);`, the output become :

> id from constructor 1
>
> Erreur de segmentation

gdb give me the error :

```
#0  0x00007ffff7f84b20 in pugi::xml_node::child(char const*) const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpugixml.so.1
#1  0x00005555555578ba in Foo::bar (this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /home/guillaume/dev/C++/projects/moteur_de_calcul/test/test_xml_node.cpp:42
#2  0x00005555555575ec in main () at /home/guillaume/dev/C++/projects/moteur_de_calcul/test/test_xml_node.cpp:73
```

The file lbl-maj_for_test.dat is a txt file of 132 lines and none seems to have a length more than 50 characters. I think to a an encoding problem, but I have no clue how I can resolve this problem ...

Comment: Guess: Accessing nodes inside `doc` probably requires `doc` to still be alive - you're not keeping a handle on it so undefined behavior ensues

Comment: I'd guess the opposite @Mat. Sounds like pugixml's `load_data` opens the file but doesn't close it. So when OP tries to open the same file again in `read_ascii_file`, they're getting a segfault.

Comment: A segfault is a strange outcome for a file read failure, @scohe001. Plus multiple read handles is usually permitted.

Comment: I agree with @Mat - that failure to keep `doc` alive is very suspicious

Comment: That's news to me. But you make a good point with the segfault @Lightness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `getline`. Uncommenting/commenting things when your program has *undefined behaviour* can lead to red herrings such as this.

The problem is that your nodes are all dangling, since you do not persist `doc`. By the time you call `bar()`, `_base_node` is dead/invalid/orphaned.

From [the documentation](https://pugixml.org/docs/quickstart.html):

> xml_document is the owner of the entire document structure; destroying the document destroys the whole tree.

Assuming the library supports it, I'd *move* `doc` into `Foo` and store it as a member by value.

Comment: ok, I haven't been careful enough about how to use the library ... by moving the xml_document object entirely, it's working. Thank you.